# Regress later LSMC

Tags: regression, american-options, least-square-monte-carlo

I am looking at the regress-later LSMC introduced by Broadie, Glasserman Ha.

This can be found here:

[*Simulation for American Options: Regression Now or Regression Later?*
by Paul Glasserman and Bin Yu](https://www0.gsb.columbia.edu/faculty/pglasserman/Other/glasserman_yuR1.pdf)

Let $X_t$ and $V_{t}$ denote the underlying Markov process value function at $t$. My understanding of this method is that it project $\Gamma V_{t+1}$ onto basis functions $\phi_j(X_{t+1})$, where $\Gamma$ is chosen such subject to some the sample conditional expectation of the basis function matches the the conditional expectation of the basis function. The conditional $\mathbb{E}(\phi(X_{t+1})|X_t)$ is computed analytically.

I tried to implement this and came up with a few observations:

1. The projection $\Gamma$ is very expensive and can be more expensive than the linear regression itself.
2. The requirement of computation of the conditional expectation affectively limit the Markov process to things with analytical values (such as GBM or Exponential OU type of model with polynomials.)
3. In the example I tried, I saw no improvement. I implemented in-sample LSMC. The values from the naive regress now and this regress later approach gave similar standard error.

I am wondering if others tried to use this method and has similar type of observation. I found papers claiming contrary results such as this one:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/314420750_Regress-Later_Least_Squares_Monte_Carlo_Duality_Perspective_and_Energy_Real_Option_Application